# WP_Query and tag ID

Tags: wordpress, loops

I am having issues while trying to build up a following query in Wordpress using the tag_id as a filter:

```
    <?php 
        $the_query = new WP_Query( array ( 
        'posts_per_page' => '-1', 
        'tag_id' => '' 
        ) );
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    ?>
```

As you can see, the "tag_id" value is empty because I am trying to retrieve the value from here:

```
        <?php echo of_get_option('slideshow-tags', 'no entry' ); ?>
```

This echo is returning a value so it works but I don't know how to adapt this to the query without getting php errors.

I tried:

```
    <?php 
        $the_query = new WP_Query( array ( 
        'posts_per_page' => '-1', 
        'tag_id' => 'echo of_get_option('slideshow-tags', 'no entry' );             '
        ) );
              while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    ?>
```

but it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to `echo` the returned value of `of_get_option`, you want to use it in your array:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array( 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'tag_id' => of_get_option('slideshow-tags', 'no entry')
));

// Now just do the loop...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Joseph Silber! I tried your code and worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

try to use this:

```
$code_to_display = of_get_option('slideshow-tags', 'no entry' );
'tag_id' => '$code_to_display'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer Vasilii. However, what Joseph says it's true and provides the answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

This was the OP's answer, added to the question, and moved here to comply with site guidelines.

---

Here's the answer for future reference:

```
        <?php 
        $the_query = new WP_Query( array ( 
        'posts_per_page' => '-1', 
        'tag_id' => of_get_option('slideshow-tags', 'no entry') 
        ) );
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        ?>
```